# How do I analyze the stability of a system with Lyapunov method?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am a student and I am studying **Lyapunov stability**. I am considering the following system:

$\dot{x_1}=x_2+x_3$

$\dot{x_2}=-asinx_1-bx_2$

$\dot{x_3}=-asinx_1-x_3$

and I want to **study its stability at the origin**. I am having some troubles understanding how to operate.

I have understood that the first thing to do is to choose a candidate **Lyapunov function**, but in this case I dont' understand how to choose it.

I know it has to be **positive definite**, so I should choose something like:

$V(x)=x^TPx$

con $P$ positive definite and symmetric.

But in my case I don't find really easy finding a lyapunov function.

I have a sketch of solution for this, and as Lyapunov function has been chosen:

$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^Tx+a(1-cosx_1)$

but to be honest I have not clear why.

I have studied that it can be used the **Graient Method** to find a Lyapunov function. I have seen that this method starts directly from the gradient of the Lyapunov function, imposing that it has to be less or equal to zero, so negative semi definite, but I have not clear how to use it.

I have also seen that it is possible to use an **indirect method**, which consists in considering a linear approximation of the original nonlinear model, and sudying the stability of the linearized model with the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix.

This method seems much simpler than choosing a Lyapunov function and working in the direct way, but can I always use it? I have seen that the equilibrium point should be isolated, but how do I check this?

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: I updated the answer because it was only true for $b \neq 1$.

Comment: The Lyapunov function is $\frac12 x_2^2+\frac12 x_3^2+a(1-\cos x_1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are multiple question, I will try to answer some of them.

I assume that $a, b > 0$.

An equilibrium is isolated if there does not exist a small "ball" around it such that it is the only equilibrium in that ball. For example:

$$
\dot{x_1} = 0
$$

has no isolated equilibrium because no matter how close you look at an equilibrium, there are always infinitely many other equilibrium points close by. Similiar, the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_1 - x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= x_1 - x_2 \\
\end{align}
$$

has no isolated equilibrium: For example $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ is is an equilibrium, but so is $x_1 = x_2 = 1.1$ and $x_1 = x_2 = 1.01$ and $x_1 = x_2 = 1.00000001$ and so on. No matter how close you look, there are always "more" equilibrium points.

---

So to your example, you have:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 + x_3 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -a \sin(x_1) - b x_2 \\
\dot{x}_3 &= -a \sin(x_1) + x_3
\end{align}
$$

To get the equilibrium points you set $\dot{x} = 0$ so you need $x_2 = -x_3$ from the first equation. Then you get

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_2 &= \dot{x}_3 = 0 \\
\implies -a \sin(x_1) - b x_2 &= -a \sin(x_1) + x_3 \\
\implies -b x_2 &= x_3 \\
\implies -b x_2 &= -x_2
\end{align}
$$

We assumed that $b > 0$ and if $b \neq 1$ the last equation can only be true if $x_2 = 0$ and then $x_3 = 0$. If you insert that you get

$$
-a \sin(x_1) = 0
$$

so the equilbrium points are $x_1 = \sin(k \pi), k \in \mathbb{Z}, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 0$. Although that means you have infinitly many equilibrium points they are all isolated because the roots of $\sin(x_1) = 0$ are isolated. Conclusion: You can use Lyapunov method.

If $b = 1$ the system has no isolated equilibrium points.

---

You can use indirect method but it will only tell you local results and sometimes you can't use it (if you get zero eigenvalues).

---

You have the function

$$
V(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^T x + a(1 - \cos(x_1))
$$

but it is not a Lyapunov function for your system:

$$
\dot{V}(x) = - b x_2^2 + x_1 x_2 - x_3^2 + x_1 x_3
$$

If $x_3 = 0$ and $x_1 = 2 b x_2$ you get $\dot{V}(x) = b x_2^2$ and that is positive no matter how small you make $x_2$. So this function can't be used.